# TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'do_farasa_tokenization'

Tags: python, nlp, ara

I get an error when running this code

```
from arabert.preprocess import ArabertPreprocessor, never_split_tokens
from farasa.stemmer import FarasaStemmer

stemmer = FarasaStemmer(interactive=True)
train_df['tweet'] = train_df['tweet'].apply(lambda x: ArabertPreprocessor(x, do_farasa_tokenization=True , farasa=stemmer, use_farasapy = True))
```

**TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'do_farasa_tokenization'**

Comment: Where is  the function `ArabertPreprocessor` defined?

Comment: from arabert.preprocess import ArabertPreprocessor, never_split_tokens

Comment: Just checked the `arabert` library on GitHub. It seems `do_farasa_tokenization` is not a parameter of the `ArabertPreprocessor` class.

Comment: Thanks, but I saw a lot of notebooks using it just fine, but still not working for me.
In the end, I used something different, which did what I want.

Comment: ```from farasa.stemmer import FarasaStemmer
stemmer = FarasaStemmer(interactive=True)
train_df['tweet'].apply(lambda x: stemmer.stem(x))```